# Cant find my project in the Instruments for memory profiling

Tags: ios4, ipad, memory-leaks, instruments

I am trying to run leak checks on my app, but could not find it in the "Choose target section". I have all other apps listed except mine.

Comment: I am able to invoke instruments from xcode : Run -> Run With Performance Tool -> Leaks. But i wonder why my project does not show up when i have ipad connected with all other apps except mine

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 4. I did Product->Perform Action->Profile Without Building

When the Instruments app comes up you should notice you app is now in the selected dropdown and you'll have to drag and drop what tools you want to use to monitor your app from the library.